# List.sort returns null

Tags: dart

I have the following method that retrieves a list of `Budget`s from an API and sorts them prior to processing:

```
response['budgets']
        .map((budget) => Budget.fromJson(budget))
        .toList()
        .sort((a, b) => budgetComparator(a, b))
        .forEach((budget) => addBudget(budget));
```

The `budgetComparator` is a method that returns an `int` between -1 and 1:

```
  int budgetComparator(Budget a, Budget b) {
    String purposeA = purposeById(a.purposeId).name,
           purposeB = purposeById(b.purposeId).name;
    return purposeA.compareTo(purposeB);
  }
```

When I run the above, I get the error message:

> NoSuchMethodError: The method 'forEach' was called on null

When debugging, I was able to observe that:

- the `sort()` method was indeed returning `null`
- the `toList()` method returns a list of 8 `Budget` items
- the `budgetComparator` ALWAYS returns an integer that is either -1, 0 or 1

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `sort` method are indeed returning null:
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/List/sort.html

What you can do if you still want to make a one liner is make use of the cascade notation:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-

```
response['budgets'].map((budget) => Budget.fromJson(budget)).toList()
  ..sort((a, b) => budgetComparator(a, b))
  ..forEach((budget) => addBudget(budget));
```

So instead of running `forEach` on the result of `sort` we will instead here run `forEach` on the list from `toList` after `sort` has been called on the list.

Answer (score 0):

`List.sort` *mutates* the existing `List`.  It does not return a new `List`.